# compilation error : library not found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use the wavelet libraries for c++ (https://sourceforge.net/projects/wavelet2d/files/wavelib-0.4.0.0/) on my MacOSx and having hard trouble in making it work.

Here is my command line :

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/wavelib -L /usr/local/lib -lwavelet2d testWavelib3.cpp -o testWavelib3
```

I get the following error :

```
library not found for -lwavelet2d
```

The library file is named `'libwavelet2d.so.1'` in the directory `/usr/local/lib`.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the lib you have is for the right architecture? You also need to move the .cpp file in front of the library in the argument list

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you have `libwavelet2d.so.1` in `/usr/local/lib`, but not `libwavelet2d.so`.  Typically what this means is that you have installed the "runtime package" for this library but not the "development package".  There should be a symlink `/usr/local/lib/libwavelet2d.so -> libwavelet2d.so.1`.

You can make the symlink yourself to try it:

```
ln -s libwavelet2d.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libwavelet2d.so
```

At build time, the file without the version suffix (`.1`) is required.  At runtime, only the suffixed file will be referenced.